# Calculate the norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

If we define the operator $S:C_0\rightarrow{C_0}$ as $[S_x](n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{x(k)y(k)}$ with $y\in{l_1}$ and  $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$.

What is its norm?

I only have managed to prove that $||y||\geq||T||$, but I don't know if the other inequality is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: To give you the idea: Assume that $y(k)\ge 0$ for all $k$. Then choose $x = (1,1,1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$ and consider the first entry of $S_x$..

Comment: But, that prove the inequality that I have already know.

Comment: Why should it prove that. Of course it doesn't, because this is an example. You have to add more and more ones, dude. ;o)

Comment: Ok, I have just known what do you mean